# React Props not getting displayed Uncaught Type Error(Plz Check out the Image Link to see full code )

Tags: reactjs, web, react-props

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grzyH.jpg)When I try to display the prop that I'm passing it just turn to pure white screen but when I log them to console it works fine no error no white screens I'm confused because the error I'm getting is Uncaught Type Error

```js
import React from 'react'
import Key from './Key'
import "./piano.css";
const Piano = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="piano">
        <Key note = "c"/>
        <Key note = "c#"/>
        <Key note = "d"/>
        <Key note = "d#"/>
        <Key note = "e"/>
        <Key note = "f"/>
        <Key note = "f#"/>
        <Key note = "g"/>
        <Key note = "g#"/>
        <Key note = "a"/>
        <Key note = "a#"/>
        <Key note = "b"/>
        {/* <Key note = "C"/> */}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Piano
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQgGp.jpg)

Comment: Please post the full error you're seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the `Key` component.

```
<p>{this.props}</>
```

function components take `props` as an argument, so `this.props`. will be undefined.

It looks like you intend to render the note prop, so you should write it like this instead:

```
<p>{props.note}</p>
```